# How can you convert curl requests into json in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an app that takes curl requests, parses it and populates a form with headers, body, url. I'm looking for a package that can convert curl requests into JSON. The curl requests will have headers, body, url and params. Any ideas? I have tried curl-parser and curl-parses-js without any success. Thanks in advance

Comment: This curl request can't be converted to a fetch or axios request?

Comment: Yes, I guess it can be done. The app (school project) I am working on will be used something like postman, but with requests can be constructed via a form or the input fields could be populated with parameters from the curl. That's why I thought converting it toJSON first would be easier.